# How to create a solana compatible wallet in rust?

Tags: rust, wallet

I'm trying to implement a desktop based wallet using Rust. I'm unsure how does solana generates a private key and public key ? Any library or codebase which could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There is an SDK that offers keygen functionality.

You can see the source code on [github](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/tree/master/sdk/src/signer), and check out the [docs](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/rust-api).

In essence, you can use their functions to generate your keys (including deriving them from a passphrase), or get inspired by the source code and write your own.